# Serialized object not received as expected

Tags: java, serialization

I have a server program and a client program.
I made a class that represents a person in my game.
In that class I have multiple variables like position, name, level....
The server sends a man-object to the client, when the client walks around with that man it changes the position in the class and the client sends the whole man-object back to the server. The problem is when I sent that object, the position always changes back to (5,5)(start position). I am almost sure that the problem is related to the socket because I created messageboxes that show each time the position that is sent and the position that is received.
Any help?

Comment: Socket does not change anything. I guess you are using serializable java objects, so make sure your fields are not transient. And show your code if you want us to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `ObjectOutputStream.reset().` See the Javadoc for why.